# Is there a method of turning off the Gmail App's Auto-resize feature in an email's layout?

Tags: android, html, mobile, responsive-design, gmail

I'm laying out an email to be viewed across browsers and mobile platforms and mostly all is going well. It's laid out in tables, using inline styling etc. However, despite a media-query to the effect of a 600px max-width, the Gmail app on at least my and one other Android I have access to is opting to resize the images and layout to fit into it's area instead of using the media query or letting it fit itself into the window normally, either of which would be fine.

For personal use, I'm able to 'turn off auto-resize' on my phone, and then the email lays out as it would in a browser.

Is there a means to either tell the Gmail app not to auto-resize from the email size or to use the media query instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Google does itself (sic!) [here](https://litmus.com/scope/tniv3plrsxkj) you should add a small hack on top of your template, right after your `<body>` tag:

```
<!-- Gmail hack -->
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff; line-height:0; width:600px !important; min-width:600px !important; max-width:600px !important;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
<!-- /Gmail hack -->
```

Since Gmail and Inbox will ignore the `display:none`, the hack will affect only those two clients.

Comment: it works for ios gmail app, but not for android gmail app

Comment: Bummer.. It worked on both platforms but I can now reproduce the problem on my Android phone.

Comment: @duchuy is working on my lenovo-phone (960*540, android 4.4)

Comment: It's working for me on Android  (Vivo Z1 Pro Funtouch OS) Gmail app.

Answer (score 13):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Then set the `style` attribute on an image (1px gif works) that spans the full width of the page (`style="min-width:600px;"`). Everything will be laid out correctly, and it'll be scrollable.

Gmail in general doesn't support media queries, or the style tag in general, which is why we have to move everything inline.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going through a CRM as an intermediary for the email campaign, and I can't actually put anything in the `<head>`. Though I didn't see that really work well in my testing anyhow, is there any way to use (or make the same effect) a meta tag like that outside of the `<head>` and not break the internet?

Comment: Woah, ok. I rarely change my head, so are you allowed to at least have a global '<head>' for all of your emails?
You can put meta tags outside of the head but yeah I wouldn't recommend it either. If you run it through email on acid or litmus you can see how it'll look. Litmus is free for a week and you can see all the clients.

You're really going to want that viewport tag if you're doing a media query / responsive email. Sideways scrolling on mobile is a big no no. The default mail app supports media queries and style tags if you want to test.

Comment: Yea, I'm using Email on Acid, unfortunately it looks like when going through the altered conditions of the CRM, none of the mobile devices are interpreting it properly. I do have the viewport tag in the top of the body, however.

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/override-gmail-mobile-optimized-email/#article-header-id-3), this block of code solved my issue.
Place it right before `</body>`.

```
<table class="gmail-app-fix">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="1"; style="line-height: 1px; min-width: 200px;">
                        <img src="transparent.gif" width="200" height="1" style="display: block; max-height: 1px; min-height: 1px; min-width: 200px; width: 200px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="1"; style="line-height: 1px; min-width: 200px;">
                        <img src="transparent.gif" width="200" height="1" style="display: block; max-height: 1px; min-height: 1px; min-width: 200px; width: 200px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="1"; style="line-height: 1px; min-width: 200px;">
                        <img src="transparent.gif" width="200" height="1" style="display: block; max-height: 1px; min-height: 1px; min-width: 200px; width: 200px;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Tested with Gmail 6.0 and Inbox 1.20 on Android 5.0.1, resolution 720x1280 (works on both portrait and landscape orientation)).

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I did not need the <img> tags, just the <td>s worked fine.

Comment: This solution negates all responsive layout — it's a rigid "stick" which props the layout from inside and prevents responsive-ness! It didn't help me. For posterity, we're talking about iOS Gmail app 6.0.210530.

Answer (score 0):

I just added style="min-width:290px;" to my outer most table, which is the smallest size my responsive emails view and its stopped moveong my blocks around and doesn't auto-resize.  This means in Gmail App the email shows as a whole email.

Comment: Where did you get 290px from?

Comment: Interestingly, on my template, setting `min-width:290px` did disable the "Revert auto-sizing" option in iOS Gmail app 6.0.210530. The layout was still mangled as before and in my case, clicking "Revert auto-sizing" manually does fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to apply a `min-width: 600px` to the outermost table in my template. This worked on the Android Gmail application. (Note that my layout uses 600 pixels. Your layout might be different)