# inline-block element containing text in Outlook (responsive emailing)

Tags: html, css, outlook

AFAIK there is no support to `display` CSS property on Outlook (not even on Outlook 2013), but I would like to know if there is an already by-default `display:inline-block` styled tag (element) where I can put text inside.

I need to put 2 blocks side-by-side on a responsive emailing on "desktop" version and vertically lined up on "mobile". (I know it's not device specific, but to call it somehow)

- Desktop: Left block is text, right block is an image.
- Mobile: Top block is the text, then the image.

Both blocks have the same width and height and everything is working nicely on mobile clients and desktop webmails (using `display:inline-block`), but not Oulook.

For an emailing based on images this is an easy task, however mixing with text it's being like mixing oil and water.

**Question:**
Is there any HTML tag that can contain text that it is already a `display:inline-block` by default on Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance I'd use a two column table with the text in the left cell and the image in the right. You can apply a CSS class to the `td` in a media query to then stack them up on mobile. Something like:

#### HTML

```
<td class="colsplit" align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
  text
</td>
<td class="colsplit" align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
  image
</td>
```

#### CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {  
  td.colsplit{
    display: block!important;
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue with Outlook but introduces another one with Gmail on Android. It's showing 2 columns and images and texts are being scaled ignoring their defined width and height. Outlook support is perfect, also tested on iOS and webmail.

Comment: @EdgarGriñant as far as I know the Gmail on Android (app or in Android browser) doesn't (yet) support responsive design - see http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/ for more information on what we can and can't use.

Comment: Nevermind I think I found a "solution", well not really but it's acceptable, based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18389474/1280669 putting an image outside the table with `min-width` equal to the width of the 2 block table (desktop version) I get the 2 columns layout working on Android, then (I still have to try it) I can tune this `min-width` from media queries for the rest of the clients to preserve the 1 column layout. On the meanwhile, I accept your answer for solving the issue and putting me on the right track. Thanks!